# Button on webpage going 'behind' elements regardless of Z-index, position is defined as fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have no idea what to do with this button anymore (the "donate" one [here](http://children.essentiads.com)).
I have used a plug-in in parallel for the mobile version which works just fine with a defined position of `fixed`.

This is also fixed position but the "donate" button keeps going behind pretty much all the elements which looks very bad since I want it on top :( any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, verifyable example within your question. That being said, z-index is relative to parent elements with non-static positioning, so if you have your `z-index:999` property on an element that's nested in a `z-index:-1` element, it will still be behind other elements.

Comment: Remove button from there, put it after your `container row`.. it's worked

Comment: Thank you! I have put it into a different container separately, The Z-index was affected by the main element's position just like you said. Now it works perfectly! thank you very very much!

Answer (score 0):

U should remove that button from there! Copy this element with id `donate_widget`, and paste it before container with class `at-content`.
I think this should work!

Comment: I have moved that element as stand-alone and it now works perfectly. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar issues with z-index as well. Here you can find some information about it https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/

As for your solution, considering the button is fixed position for the whole web page (not just one section) you could maybe move it up in the HTML tree. In other words, make it a direct descendant of the body element - or row, or something which is above your other elements.

Comment: I have moved it up the HTML tree basically, made it stand-alone not parrented; That fixed it, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found it. So I went to the parent element and the div with the id fws_577e3c5a64f62 that contains the button should have the high z-index. This seems to fix the problem for me.

Comment: Thank you, I have made it a stand-alone element, not parrented to anything and it works! Thank you very much for the help, you're awesome guys!